# Functions with multiple Foreach-Object

Tags: function, powershell, foreach

I have a part of my script that doesn't work. The goal is, to take files from a folder, filter and organise them by an aspect of their filename, and move them to a new folder which has had new directories made for them. i.e organised by month and year based on file name. E.g. 032 Approved warranty - Croatia - Case-2019 08-1419032, goes into a directory 2019, then 08.
The next step was creating a select all function, which cycled through numbers 01-12. Which it does fine. Now the issue is I want to cycle for each year as well between 2017-2019. Which is where i'm stuck.

This is my trial code which doesn't work:

```
function DoWork {
    Param([int]$Month) ([int]$Year)

    $StrMonth = $Month.ToString("00")
    echo $StrMonth.ToString("00")

    $StrYear = $Year.ToString
    echo $StrYearToString

    $files = Get-ChildItem $destinationpath -Filter "*$StrYear $StrMonth*" -Recurse

    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $year = $Year.ToString()
        $month = $Month.ToString()
        $file.Name
        $StrYear
        $StrMonth

        # Set Directory Path
        $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $StrYear + "\" + $StrMonth
        if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
            New-Item $directory -Type Directory
        }

        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $Directory -Force
    }
}

if ($group1 -eq 'Select All') {
    2017..2019 | ForEach-Object {
        $year = $_
        1..12 | ForEach-Object {DoWork($_, $year)}
    }
} elseif ($group -eq 'Select All') {
    1..12 | ForEach-Object {DoWork($_, $group1)}
} else {
    DoWork($group, $group1)
}
```

I want it to loop through a year, then all the months, then the next year etc. And make folders for them on the other side. I can't quite suss it. The error message is:

```
DoWork : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Month'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]"
value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
At line:46 char:39
+         1..12 | ForEach-Object {DoWork($_, $year)}
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [DoWork], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,DoWork
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your function definition

The line

```
function DoWork { param ([int]$Month) ([int]$Year)
```

should be something like

```
function DoWork { 

    param ( [int] $Month, [int] $Year)  

    # your function code...
}
```

Comment: + he'll need to change `DoWork($_, $year)` to `DoWork $_ $year`

Comment: Your're right ;-)

Comment: This error pops up now:   Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At line:13 char:1
+ Echo $StrMonth.ToString("00")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: @WilliamBrooker `$StrMonth` is already a string, not sure what you're trying to achieve here